# jQuery UI Accordion Positioning

Tags: css, jquery-ui

So I am using an accordion as the first step in a 2-step vertical registration process. I have the accordion as step one on top with a few consent forms, and once they are all accepted, step 2 is enabled.

My problem is that the accordion panes seem to be positioned absolutely, and they cover up the divs below the accordion when open. How can I get the accordion panes to come back into the page flow, having the divs below move with the opening and closing of the accordion.

I've tried positioning them relatively, but it does not seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this. I had a set height for the accordion, it was relatively positioned. Removing the set height fixed it.